# Power BI : Dynamic Colors for TopN values on Clutered Column Chart

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas, powerbi-desktop

**Requirement:** Assign dynamic colors to the subcategory values on the clustered column chart.

**Background:**
The chart shows Top 6 subcategories by SalesAmount and rest other categories as Others. There is a filter on subcategory in the filter pane on All Pages level

**Partial Solution & the Problem:** I have created a measure [SelectedSubcategoryColor] that does returns dynamic colors but it only works when more than 5 subcategories are selected. If less than 5 subcategories are selected, then the visual breaks. I want the visual to work even if 1 subcategory is selected

[here is the link to the pbix file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsvLF4iggeEsuUPjF1ocI9rxarWt?e=WymNTq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The measure you've shared calculates the sales amount for the Top 6 subcategories and other categories as "Others." I tried to modify your
SelectedSubcategoryColor as below :

```
SelectedSubcategoryColor =
VAR _CurrentSubcategory = SELECTEDVALUE ( Subcategory[SubcategoryName] )
VAR _AllSubcategories = ALLSELECTED( Subcategory )
VAR _CurrentRank = RANKX( _AllSubcategories, [Sales], , DESC )
RETURN
    SWITCH(
        TRUE(),
        _CurrentRank = 1, "Red",
        _CurrentRank = 2, "Green",
        _CurrentRank = 3, "Blue",
        _CurrentRank = 4, "Orange",
        _CurrentRank = 5, "Purple",
        _CurrentRank = 6, "Yellow",
        _CurrentSubcategory = "Others", "Grey",
        "Black"
    )
```

So even if my selection doesn't apply to the measure it won't break :
[image]

[image]

Otherwise :

[image]